# Removing lines with empty fields in CSV by sed

Tags: sed

I have a CSV file with two columns. The first is ID (int) and the second is text. All lines have the ID column. I want to remove files where the second column is empty (zero-length or space only).

I tried

```
sed -i '/^[0-9]+,\s*$/d' file.csv
```

but it does not work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to escape the `+` or use `\{1,\}` or add `-E` for extended regex:

```
sed -i '/^[0-9]\+,\s*$/d' file.csv
sed -i '/^[0-9]\{1,\},\s*$/d' file.csv
sed -Ei '/^[0-9]+,\s*$/d' file.csv
```

Or use `grep`:

```
grep -v '^[0-9]\+, *$' file.csv
```

However, I'd prefer a proper csv parser:

```
csvgrep -S -c2 -r '.' file.csv
```